# SQL Update Statement in Powershell Issue with Website Escape Charactor

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to Iterate through a CSV file to do an Update Query in SQL. The CSV has Websites, a nickname for a site, and a resource group. It is having issues reading the website because it contains / which I think is an escape charactor. Is there a way to format WHERE SITES = $($c.sites) so it doesnt throw the following error? `Invoke-SQLcmd : Incorrect syntax near 'https:'`. The sites look like https://fakesite.com/something

````
foreach($c in $csv){

$updatequery="
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
SET SiteName = $($c.sitename), RSG_Name= $($c.Resource_Group)
WHERE SITES = $($c.sites)
GO"}

Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'serverinstance' -query $updatequery -Database db```
````

Comment: Then is that site requires those, then you have to parse and terminate them. See the PowerShell docs regarding string termination. Since you are not showing a good example of what one of those Urls are, you are just leaving folks to guess. The one you are showing is a normal Url, which should not be giving you issues.

Comment: Look up parametrized queries and never worry about escaping again.